# Sentry/Raven passing additional data

Tags: javascript, sentry, raven

I'm trying to pass additional data with an exeption report to sentri.

Test code

```
Raven.captureMessage("test", {"blabla": "blabla"})
```

In sentri admin I can see the error, but can't find any additional data. Am I missing something, is it somewhere hidden, or do I miss the purpose of additional data parameter?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out that it accepts only {tags: ...} and/or {extras: ...} parameters. And also would note, that it uses only extras from last recieved exception, so cannot be used for some specific infos like logs from users session etc.